# Looking for unique count of names in a queue

Tags: java, queue

In this queue I am confused on how I am suppose to count the number of unique names. Example: (James,John,James,Ken,Debbie,Ben) are in the array and I am suppose to receive the result of 4 unique names (the unique names are John,Ken,Debbie,Ben). But I do not not know how to count the unique String name in Java.

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(Queue<String> args) {
    Queue<String> a=new Queue<String>();
    int n=0;
    while(n<5){
        System.out.print("Enter name");
        a.add(name);
        n=n+1
    }
    System.out.print("the number of unique names are"+ unique.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @matoni points out the `Set` class will prevent duplicates. But concerning your specification you have an additional requirement: A non unique name should not be counted. This cannot be achieved by a `Set` alone (e.g. the `Set` will contain the name "James" and so would be counted).

I'd suggest this little trick: You insert the names in a `HashSet` (a non abstract implementation of `Set`) called `uniqueNames`. If a name already exists in the `uniqueNames`, you insert them in a separate `HashSet` named `nonUniqueNames`. To count the unique names (according to your definition) you only have to substract the size of `nonUniqueNames` from the size of `uniqueNames`.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String[] names = new String[] {"James","John","James","James","Ken","Debbie","Ben"};
        HashSet<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> nonUniqueNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
            if (!uniqueNames.add(names[i])) {
                // uniqueNames.add failed because the name already
                // exists in the HashSet. So insert it in nonUniqueNames:
                nonUniqueNames.add(names[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(
            "The number of unique names is "+
            (uniqueNames.size()-nonUniqueNames.size())
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some implementation of `Set` e.g. `TreeSet` where you add all `Queue`'s items. `Set` structure automatically suppress duplicates.

```
Queue<String> names = new LinkedList<>();
// your code...
Set<String> uniqueNames = new TreeSet<>(names);
int numberOfUniqueNames = uniqueNames.size();
// do something with count...
```

Comment: are there any suggestion for things to do with uniqueNames(for (String name: uniqueNames){}  else its not really important to modify it right

Comment: you are right, for-each loop was not important there

Comment: if i do not write my code like this "Queue<String> names=new LinkedList<String>();" the Queue will have some error which i cant solve it and the part where i do "int numberofuniqueNames=uniqueNames.size();" can i just do System.out.print("number of unique names are" + numberofuniqueNames);

Comment: when I used your piece of code (Queue) I forgot, that `Queue` is just an Interface, which can not be instantiated. Interface is just contract, that says which methods you can except, when working with variable of interface type.  To create object of such type, you need to instantiate implementation of the interface. In case of `Queue` it can be e.g. `LinkedList`. There are also other queue implementations, but `LinkedList` is the most common.